Created a New Elasticsearch Index with Old Mappings but Queries Return Empty Results
I recently created a new Elasticsearch index (index_ad_sm_v2_test) and copied the mappings from an existing index (index_ad_sm). Here is the mapping I used:
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "routing": {
                "allocation": {
                    "include": {
                        "_tier_preference": "data_content"
                    }
                }
            },
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "1"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "address": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "brand": {
                "properties": {
                    "created_at": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "updated_at": {
                        "type": "date"
                    }
                }
            },
            "brand_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "city": {
                "properties": {
                    "created_at": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "latitude": {
                        "type": "float"
                    },
                    "longitude": {
                        "type": "float"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "updated_at": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "weight": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            },
            "city_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "count_rate": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "created_at": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "latitude": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "longitude": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "params": {
                "properties": {
                    "ad_specialized_machinery_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "blade_cutting_depth": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "blade_tilt_angle": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "body_height": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "body_length": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "body_type": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "body_volume": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "body_width": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "boom_length": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "bucket_volume": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "digging_depth": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "drilling_diameter": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "engine_power": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "fence_depth": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "fuel_tank_capacity": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "grip_depth": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "grip_width": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "laying_width": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "lift_height": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "load_capacity": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "maximum_drilling_depth": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "milling_width": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "number_of_axles": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "number_of_rollers": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "operating_pressure": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "platform_length": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "platform_width": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "refrigerator_temperature_max": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "refrigerator_temperature_min": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "roller_diameter": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "roller_type": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "roller_width": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "tank_volume": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "temperature_range": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "turning_radius": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "undercarriage_type": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "unloading_gap_width": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "unloading_radius": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "water_tank_volume": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            },
            "price": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "rating": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "type": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "sub_category_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            },
            "type_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "updated_at": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "user": {
                "properties": {
                    "access_role": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "birth_date": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "can_driver": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "can_owner": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "city_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "created_at": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "document_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "email": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "first_name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "iin": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "last_name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "owner_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "phone_number": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rating": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "updated_at": {
                        "type": "date"
                    }
                }
            },
            "user_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "documents": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "created_at": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "extension": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "path": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "shareLink": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "size": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "updated_at": {
                        "type": "date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I expected the new index to work the same as the old one, but when I run queries (e.g., match_all or multi_match) on the new index, it always returns an empty result set, even though I confirmed that documents exist in the index.
What could be causing the new index to return empty results?
Is there any additional step required when copying mappings to ensure the index functions correctly?
Could there be an issue with how data was indexed or transferred?
Any insights on what might be going wrong would be helpful. Thanks!"

I think you need to show code you’re using to query and maybe some example documents as json.
